# Ocultar senha no terminal

Tags: python

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em python que vai funcionar pelo terminal

Em certo momento, preciso realizar um login:

```
print('É necessário informar suas credenciais para se comunicar com a API')
email = input('Email: ')
password = input('Senha: ')
```

O problema é que a saída no console, fica dessa forma:

```
É necessário informar suas credenciais para se comunicar com a API:
Email: teste@teste.com
Senha: senhaTeste
```

Eu preciso que o campo senha não mostre os caracteres, que substitua por "*" ou algo do tipo:

A saída que eu procuro no terminal é algo assim:

```
É necessário informar suas credenciais para se comunicar com a API:
Email: teste@teste.com
Senha: **********
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode usar o [`getpass.getpass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/getpass.html#getpass.getpass)

```
import getpass

print('É necessário informar suas credenciais para se comunicar com a API')
email = input('Email: ')
password = getpass.getpass('Senha: ')
```

Comment: Ótimo, isso já resolve meu problema, mas você sabe se existe a possibilidade de em vez de ficar em branco a cada letra inserir um '*'? Para quem estiver usando conseguir perceber que está realmente digitando

Comment: Aí só implementando algo, @JoséHenriqueLuckmann. Eu não acho boa ideia, nunca vi um terminal mostrar asteriscos enquanto se digita uma senha, além de que é muito mais trabalho pra pouco resultado.

Comment: Não aparecem `*` nos terminais por questão de segurança... Sabendo a quantidade de caracteres de uma senha fica muita mais fácil de fazer um brute force... É uma decisão de design

Comment: E +1 para a resposta e para a pergunta. Não conhecia este módulo

Answer (score 1):

Se você quer que isso aconteça **no terminal**, você vai ter que criar uma nova função de input e importá-la depois, a partir da função input() original em C [( disponível aqui a partir da linha 1832 )](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/bltinmodule.c). Parece ser algo relativamente fácil se você compreende um pouco como o compilador funciona. Até onde sei, ainda não existe uma solução de alto nível para esse problema.

Comment: Muito bom saber, para o momento a solução apresentada pelo @LINQ é a mais viável. Mas quando sobrar um tempo vou brincar um pouco com isso e tentar desenvolver